# How to best performance wise join a column from right table into left list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

accountAging and I'm trying to add notes that belong to an accountId that are in an accountNotes db table into the AccountNotes field of accountsAging list.   I first tried this approach:

```
            foreach (var account in accountAging)
            {
                account.AccountsReceivableNotes = accountNotesList.Where(n => n.AccountId == account.AccountId).Select(n => n.Content).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But I wanted to avoid a loop for performance reasons as I have a lot of data.

An article suggested doing a join for better performance.  So I tried this below.  However, I was wondering if there as an easy way to assign all the fields in accountAging without specifying each one.  There are more than 15+ fields.  This approach below wipes out all the values that were in the other fields in AccountAging and just gives me AccountNotes.  The loop of course works but trying to optimize the code.  Thanks.

```
 var c = from a in accountAging
                    join n in accountNotesRepository.All.AsEnumerable()
                    on a.AccountId equals n.AccountId
                    select new AccountAging
                    {
                      AccountNotes = n.Content 
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to speed up the code is to build a **hash map**. The key of the hash map is the `account.AccountId` and the value is `account` for all `account` in `accountNotesList`. The resulting code can just iterates over the account in `accountAging` like you did with a foreach but the slow linear walk performed by the linkq can be replaced by a constant-time hash map access. This should be also faster than a linkq join if `accountNotesList` is not significantly bigger than `accountAging`. Note that linkq tend to be quite slow compared to a carfully-optimized loop.

Comment: Thank you Jerome.  I did try a hash map and it helped.